# Variables of another host not accessible via the `hostvars` variable?

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook running plays against 2 different hosts. Here are the plays:

```yaml
- name: Backup database
  hosts: host1
  roles:
    - backup_database
  vars:
    db_backup_path: "{{ hostvars.localhost.temp_dir.path + '/' + backup_filename }}"

- name: Check the backup exists
  hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - aws
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: hostvars['host1']['db_backup_path']
```

Running this threw an error:

> The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'db_backup_path'.

I obviously assigned that variable in the previous play, so why would the second play not be able to access it?

Comment: When you are using `vars` at a play level it is locally accessible to that play only. Use a `set_fact` task so the variable persists across the other play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is described in the variables documentation page:

> You can decide where to set a variable based on the scope you want
> that value to have. Ansible has three main scopes:
>
> - Global: this is set by config, environment variables and the command line
> - Play: each play and contained structures, vars entries (vars; vars_files; vars_prompt), role defaults and vars.
> - Host: variables directly associated to a host, like inventory, include_vars, facts or registered task outputs

*<sup>Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#scoping-variables</sup>*

So, in your case, by using a `vars` at the play level, your variable `db_backup_path` is only visible for that play.

What you can do, if you want to variable to be accessible by both your role and your second play is to use a `set_fact` task in a `pre_tasks`.

So, in your case, something like:

```yaml
- hosts: host1
  gather_fact: false

  pre_tasks:
    - set_fact:
        db_backup_path: >-
          {{ hostvars.localhost.temp_dir.path }}/{{ backup_filename }}

  roles:
    - backup_database
    

- hosts: localhost
  gather_fact: false

  roles:
    - aws

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: hostvars.host1.db_backup_path
```

---

Mind that there are also voices in the Ansible team itself that would prefer the usage of `include_role` and `import_role` over the `role` keyword, which is a exception in Ansible.

So, your playbook could also be written:

```yaml
- hosts: host1
  gather_fact: false    

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        db_backup_path: >-
          {{ hostvars.localhost.temp_dir.path }}/{{ backup_filename }}

    - import_role: 
        name: backup_database
    

- hosts: localhost
  gather_fact: false

  tasks:
    - import_role: 
        name: aws

    - debug:
        var: hostvars.host1.db_backup_path
```

Which is, in my opinion, easier to read as the tasks are going to happen in the same chronological order as you read them.

Comment: so instead of assigning the `db_backup_path` variable, I originally tried using the `temp_dir` var from localhost and the `backup_filename` var from host1, but got the same error that `backup_filename` is undefined. That variable is defined in the `vars/main.yml` for the `backup_database` role. Shouldn't that variable be available via `hostvars`?

Comment: No, the variables in `vars/main.yml` of a role are, for obvious reason of separation, local only to that role. That's the exact purpose of a role actually, to be able to separate the variables/templates/tasks/handlers/... of that role from a play and make the role portable.

Comment: Still, you can "export" them the same way: put them in a `set_fact` inside your role rather than in a variable file.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Role variables are *not* local to roles unless you use `include_role` with `public: false` (this catches a lot of people off guard, especially the fact that variables from static imports are available to tasks that run *before* the role in question.) They are, however, always play scoped so they cannot be accessed from a separate play.

Comment: @flowerysong I stand corrected, thanks. Another reason to favour `(import|include)_role` over `roles`, then, if it offer that possibility.